# How do I make my Discord.py bot pick a random "line" from a .txt file in the same folder as my main code?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making an overall fun bot and I want it to pick a random colour which has been written in a .txt file. Please help either on this platform or on Discord. My Discord Username is: RelaxedNerd#3072.

Comment: Is this related to discord.py?

Comment: Ask a code related question on StackOverflow... show your own effort

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to just set them as a variable and import random such as this

```
import random

@client.command()
async def color(ctx):
    responses = ['red',
                 'blue',
                 'green',
                 'purple',
                 'Add more',]
    await ctx.send(f'Color: {random.choice(responses)}')
```